# Squaring a vector; why not use the geometric product with itself, instead of the inner product with itself?

Tags: vectors, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

The square of a vector is defined as follows:

$$
A^2 := \mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{A}
$$

However, with this definition then $\sqrt{\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{A}} = A \neq \mathbf{A}$. Thus by square rooting the square one does not go back to the original point.

Let us consider the geometric product defined as $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{A}+ \mathbf{A} \wedge \mathbf{A}$. Consider a specific example of a vector $\mathbf{v}:=a\hat{x}+b\hat{y}$.

Its inner product is $\mathbf{v} \cdot \mathbf{v} = aa+bb$, and the square root is $\sqrt{aa+bb}$.

Its geometric product is $\mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}=(a\hat{x}+b\hat{y})(a\hat{x}+b\hat{y}) = aa\hat{x}\hat{x}+a\hat{x}b\hat{y}+b\hat{y}a\hat{x}+b\hat{y}b\hat{y}$. Now, by square rooting the geometric product, one does recover the origin vector. Thus $\mathbf{A}^2=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A} \neq \mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{A}$.

Is the definition $A^2:= \mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{A}$ an archaic definition superseded by geometric algebra?

Comment: How does that square root recover $\mathbf{v}$?  What does that even mean?

Comment: What is $A$? What is $\mathbf A$? What is $\mathbf A\land \mathbf A$?

Comment: It seems like you consider $\hat{x}$ to be a vector. Then what is $\hat{x}\hat{x}$?

Comment: @Alexandre H Tremblay I don 't understand the definition of the geometric product.Isn't $\textbf{A}\cdot\textbf{A}$ a scalar and $\textbf{A}\wedge \textbf{A}$ a vector?

Comment: @Peter the geometric product yields a multivector which contains both vector and scalar elements.

Comment: @PeterMelech: The wedge product is a **bivector**, not a vector.

Comment: Since $\mathbf{A} \wedge \mathbf{A} = 0$, the square $\mathbf{A} ^2$ is indeed equal to $\mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{A}$, and “square rooting the geometric product” is exactly the same as taking the square root of the scalar $|\mathbf{A}|^2$, and there's no way of defining some kind of square root function on the geometric algebra that would always give you back the original vector. So it seems the whole question is based on some kind of misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks. So it is a vector in the exterior square. How is the addition of such a quantitaty and a scalar defined?@Hans Lundmark

Comment: @PeterMelech: It's just a formal linear combination, like “adding apples and oranges”.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark OK, thanks. Didn 't expect that

Comment: @HansLundmark Suppose $\mathbf{A}:=1+a \hat{x}$, then the geometric product is $\mathbf{A}^2=1+2a\hat{x}+aa\hat{x}\hat{x}$, which is not a scalar. Is the wedge product $\mathbf{A}\wedge \mathbf{A}=0$ only true for vector (and false for multivectors)?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay: Yes, that's for vectors only, it's not true in general (as your example shows). From your question, I was assuming that the notation $\mathbf{A}$ meant a vector all the time.

Comment: @Sambo: It's the **Clifford product** (as indicated by the tags "clifford-algebras" and "geometric-algebras").

Answer (score 3):

1. Your initial assertion, that the square of a vector $A$ is defined as $A \cdot A$, doesn't match with my experience. I've always seen that denoted by $\| A\|^2 = A \cdot A$, so that it's a statement about the square of the *length* of a vector (a nonnegative real number!), not a definition of squaring the vector itself. Perhaps I've read different areas of mathematics than you have, however.
2. You might want to consider a little more carefully the property you're trying to preserve. You're trying to be sure that $\sqrt{a^2} = a$ always. Well, even in a 1-dimensional vector space like the reals, that's not true, as 
   $$
   \sqrt{(-2)^2} = 2 \ne -2.
   $$

The property you're talking about holds (for the reals) only in the case where $a$ is nonnegative.

Of course, you *can* define a different squaring operation if you like, and prove things about it, and maybe it'll turn out to be enormously useful. But for now, I'm quite happy to use the idea of the squared length of a vector, which has proven enormously useful to me, and not worry about squaring a vector, which I've never needed to do.

Comment: Though you can just define a function $\text{Sign}(A)$ which returns the sign of $A$, and then 'correctly' define the square root as $\text{Sign}(A)\sqrt{A^2}=A$

Comment: What is the "sign" of a vector?

Comment: @Randall I was answering John's point #2 regarding real numbers. I should have said $\text{Sign}(r)\sqrt{r^2}=r$

Comment: It's quite common in physics to use the notation $\mathbf{A}^2$ as an abbreviation for $|\mathbf{A}|^2 = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{A}$, so in that case it's taken as a definition. But in the context of algebras (in this case Clifford algebras) it makes perfect sense to actually square things, so the square of a vector is well-defined, and it happens to equal the square of the length (or minus that, depending on which convention you use).

Comment: As I said, it's possible that OP and I have read stuff in different areas of mathematics (and in particular, I don't read a lot of physics).

Comment: "define a function Sign() which returns the sign of  and then correctly...". Really? In that case, what's $\sqrt{4}$?

Answer (score 1):

We have $$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B} = |\vec{A}||\vec{B}|\cos\theta$$
So, $$\vec{A}\cdot\vec{A} = |\vec{A}||\vec{A}|\cos 0 = |\vec{A}|^2$$

While taking the square root, you take the square root of a scalar and not a vector. But if you consider $\bigg[\sqrt{\vec A \cdot\vec A} \bigg]\ \hat a$ with $|\vec A| \ge0$,

$\bigg[\sqrt{\vec A \cdot\vec A} \bigg]\ \hat a = \sqrt{|\vec{A}|^2} \ \hat a =|\vec{A}|\hat a = \vec{A}$ ,  where $\hat{a}$ is the unit vector along $\vec{A}$ .

Comment: What is $\hat a$?

Comment: Unit vector in direction of $\vec{A}$. I'll add it. Thanks!

Comment: Also consider explaining what $A$ is in this answer.

Comment: @5xum I directly used $|\vec{A}|$ instead of $A$ to avoid confusion. Thanks again!

Comment: Using undefined variables is, in my opinion, the exact opposite of avoiding confusion. Anyway, nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps to note axby=abxy and by byax=-abxy by anticommutativity of distinct basisvectors in R^n the geometric product. So AA=A dot A.

Furthermore AA is a scalar. And the first root you normally use on scalars is meant to be the normal squareroot. The other squareroot you used on the geometric product is something you cannot really define since there are more vectors which the square equal to A^2, namely with the same magnitude in different directions. Thus infinite solutions.

Anticommutativity is easily proven from the axioms from wikipedia.
2=(e1+e2)(e1+e2)=e1e1+e1e2+e2e1+e2e2=2+e1e2-e1e2

e1e2=-e1e2

Sorry for the bad notation, I did this on my phone